# Embed HTML within a URL

Tags: html

Is it possible to embed HTML within a URL and then render that HTML in the browser itself?

In theory, what 'm thinking of works similarly to an URL like below:

```
http://"<h1>Hello World</h1>"
```

this would show a page with "Hello World" wrapped in a `<h1>` tag.

Of course, I understand that the above does not work in the real world for a wide range of reasons. Is there however a a way in which I can encode data within a URL and show render that data as HTML within the browser?

I understand that you could easily set up a webserver to do this, but I am interested in a solution which would work natively without any dependencies.

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstand your question, but why not put a uuid as a url param and have the javascript decode the id, and display html code on the dom that correlates to the id in the url?

Comment: @Chano's point is a valid one - you say you want something that works "natively without any dependencies" (on a web-server) - javascript is your best solution if you want to build and display html dynamically.  Can you clarify exactly what your use case is for the type of solution that you're asking for?

Answer (score 2):

It's Data URL. **Data URLs**, URLs prefixed with the data: scheme, allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents. They were formerly known as "data URIs" until that name was retired by the WHATWG.

Data URLs are treated as unique opaque origins by modern browsers, rather than inheriting the origin of the settings object responsible for the navigation.

**Syntax:**

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="data:text/html,<h1>Hello World</h1>">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) does.

```html
<a href="data:text/html,<h1>Hello World</h1>">Go to welcome page</a>
```